# Constructing a hypothesis test for "ask the audience" lifeline in "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, survey, multinomial-distribution

I wish to construct a hypothesis test that assesses whether the differences between the highest voted answer and the other answers shown when a contestant selects the "ask the audience" lifeline (in the show "Who Wants to Be a Millionaire?") are significant.

I was thinking about modeling the audience's selection in the following way:

Let $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4)$ represent the observed vote percentages, and treat these as probabilities, with $\theta_1$ representing the highest percentage, let $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ denote the number of people who select the answer choice associated with $(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4)$ (respectfully). Lastly, let $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 = n$ denote the number of people in the audience, who have the ability to vote. Now,

$$(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) \sim \textrm{Multinomial}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4|n)$$

With $n$ being fixed, if the number of voters is known, else distributed according to $\textrm{Binomial}(m,p)$, with $m$ and $p$ selected to match a given 95% confidence interval around the suspected true value of $n$.

$H_a$ being the event that differences are significant and $H_0$ otherwise. The p-value for this test is given by the following probability:
$$1 - P(X_1>X_2,X_1>X_3,X_1>X_4)$$

which is calculated by evaluating:
$$1 - \sum_{x_1 = 0}^{n}\sum_{x_2=0}^{n-x_1}\sum_{x_3 = 0}^{n - x_1 - x_2}\frac{n!}{x_1!x_2!x_3!(n-x_1-x_2-x_3)!}{\theta_{1}}^{x_1} {\theta_{2}}^{x_2}{\theta_{3}}^{x_3}{\theta_{4}}^{n-x_1-x_2-x_3}\mathbb{1}(x_1>x_2,x_1>x_3,x_1>n-x_1-x_2-x_3)$$

if $n$ is fixed. Otherwise, estimate the p-value with the following algorithm:

1. $S = 0$
2. For $L$ iterations,

   - Sample $n\sim\textrm{Binomial}(m,p)$
   - Given $n$ (and the $\theta$'s), sample $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4) \sim \textrm{Multinomial}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4|n)$
   - If $X_1>X_2$ and $X_1>X_3$ and $X_1>X_4$,

     - $S = S + 1$
3. Return $\frac{S}{L}$

I was wondering whether this is a legitimate way of going about the problem, if better models are available, or if more powerful tests can be constructed.

Comment: I'm confused what you're actually trying to test? You say "the differences between the highest voted answer and the other answers". I don't know what this means. Then you seem to be defining $\theta_1$ as the proportion of people who voted for the most-voted for answer, and $X_1$ the number of people who voted for it. You then test if $X_1$ is bigger than the other $X$'s, which it is by definition (it's the most voted for answer). Won't your p-value be 1 every time?

Comment: If you mean to test whether the most-voted-for answer is more likely to be correct, then surely you want $X = \mathcal{1}\{\text{most-voted-for answer is correct}\}$ and then $X \sim \text{Binomial}(p)$, and test $H_0$: $p = 1/4$

Comment: I'm treating the $\theta$'s as fixed probabilities, and the $X$'s as random variables. Basically, I'm allowing the voting procedure to be carried out many times, with those probabilities. If $P(X_1>X_2,X_1>X_3,X_1>X_4)$ is high, then there is a high probability the observed proportions turned out that way, instead of due to chance.

Comment: Isn't the $X$ in your second comment a Bernoulli random variable? I'm not exactly sure how that test would be carried out.

Comment: Are you talking about applying this test on just one question? I thought you meant many questions (e.g. over multiple episodes), in which case you're right, technically I mean $\Sigma X_i \sim \text{Binomial}(p)$ for i being the ith question